# Sidekiq getting ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, sidekiq, puma

I am getting an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool` exception for background jobs in Sidekiq

**CONFIG**

- I have a PUMA web process and a SIDEKIQ process running on Heroku (2 hobby dynos) [A Rails app with background jobs]
- In `database.yml` I have `pool: 40` (in `default` and `production`)
- In `sidekiq.yml` I have `:concurrency: 7`
- In `puma.rb` I have `max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("PUMA_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }` and have set `ENV["PUMA_MAX_THREADS"] = 5`
- I am using a Heroku pgsql hobby instance, which allows for `20 connections`

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

When the 7 Sidekiq workers are busy running jobs they should have enough available db connections.

Because:

Needed db connections:

- 5 for 5 PUMA threads
- 12: [7 + 5] for SIDEKIQ threads (7 workers + 5 for redis? - not sure about reasoning behind that one)
- TOTAL NEEDED: 17 [12+5]
- TOTAL AVAILABLE: 20

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR**

When the 7 Sidekiq workers are busy running jobs, 2 jobs fail and raise the `ConnectionTimeOutError` (always 2 jobs, so actual max concurrency is 5)

**STUFF I NOTICED (MIGHT HELP):**

- In SIDEKIQ dashboard, Redis connections reach a maximum 10 (never higher) [I guess 5 threads + 5]
- In Heroku db, when enqueueing a lot of jobs, connections are always much lower than the 20 available (so no problem from the pgsql instance)

Any help or advice would be super appreciated :))

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Adding my `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 10 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tracker_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: tracker_app_test

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 10 } %>
```

```
web: DB_POOL=$PUMA_MAX_THREADS bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: DB_POOL=14 bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
release: rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Can you please run this `redis-cli flushall` and retry again.

Comment: Hi @OsamaInayat thanks for suggesting that. I just tried that, restarted the dynos and still get the same exceptions :((

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to have `pool: ENV['DB_POOL']` and for the web dyno set it to 5 and for the sidekiq dyno to 14. I still ran into the same issue

Comment: It sounds like your `pool` setting in `database.yml` is not being respected. Can you share your *entire* `database.yml` file?

Comment: Shared in the post above :)) cc: @AdamMcCrea

Answer (score 3):

This exception is being raised from the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Queue` class in Rails, specifically in the `poll` method of the class, which accepts a timeout period (defaults to 5s). This is how the error is being raised:

```
if elapsed >= timeout
  msg = "could not obtain a connection from the pool within %0.3f seconds (waited %0.3f seconds); all pooled connections were in use" %
    [timeout, elapsed]
  raise ConnectionTimeoutError, msg
end
```

I think this is saying that if the time elapsed since it has tried to acquire a connection is greater than the timeout provided (default 5s) then it will raise this exception. This is happening because the number of available connections from the pool is 10, while in Sidekiq you have mentioned 14 as the default pool size. Try to increase the pool size of your web dyno to more than or equal to the number of default pool connections specified in your Sidekiq dyno. Hopefully, this resolves this exception.

If this does not work, then you can try increasing the `checkout_timeout` from 5s to a longer duration like so:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 10 } %>
  checkout_timeout: 10

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tracker_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: tracker_app_test

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 10 } %>
```

This is what the API documentation for Rails has to say about ConnectionPools.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: Hi Ghouse, thanks for you answer.

My `DB_POOL` env variable is set to 14 for the sidekiq process (you can see that in the contents of the procfile I posted above || so ActiveRecord should allow 14 connections for the Sidekiq process). 

While the SIDEKIQ concurrency is set to 7.

Or did I get the config I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

***SOLUTION FOUND:***

In my `database.yml` file, the `production` config had 1 indentation while it should have had 0...

Comment: hi, could you explain more about your solution ?

Comment: Hi Lam, I had an extra indentation in my database.yml. 

So instead of having 0 spaces before the word « production », I had 2 spaces. And I guess, that in that case the yml was not reading the « production » config